# App components not showing, but emulator is working

Tags: android

I'm trying to run my first application on Android Studio.  The emulator boots up fine and I can click on my application icon - however, only the screen in the attached image (see link) is shown despite my having put ImageView/Button attributes in my activity_main.

This is my manifest.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.aneyth.myfirstapplication">
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

   </manifest>
```

[image: Working emulator but no output]

I can get my images to show up fine in the preview "design" part of Android Studio, but they don't appear on my app when I run it.  Any thoughts?

-A

Comment: Can you please show the layout xml file and what it is supposed to look like?

Comment: My apologies.  The emulator did boot up properly after a few more tries, and after restarting Android Studio.